# SAP UI5 table and text color in Internet Explorer

Tags: sapui5, hana

I have a form which is working fine in Chrome but in IE the form looks very weird. I have two tables one is looks fine but in the other table , extra empty spaces are created between last row and the table border.

And also , for some text boxes , when i enter any value ,the text color changes to grey but normally its black in most of the cases.

I am using IE 8.

Any known solution for this issue.

Could anyone help me in resolving this issue.

BR - SS

Note : I couldnt post the snapshot of my error because i am new to this site.

Comment: Well, what have you expected really.... https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f072cf6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Comment: Hi ,  Thanks i noticed that it supports from IE 9 , but still i have two tables , one is looking sae as in chrome and other one having issue.